# Place cursor in text box Angularjs addmode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On this [site](http://centralreservations.org/) when "Add New" is clicked, I want the cursor to be placed into the first text box (**Hotel Name**). The cshtml code under that "Add New" button is

```
 <p data-ng-hide="addMode"><a data-ng-click="toggleAdd()" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary">Add New</a></p>
```

The toogleAdd() function is as follows:

```
     $scope.toggleAdd = function () {


        $("#txtHotelName").focus();
        $('#txtHotelName').select();


        $scope.action = "Create";
        $scope.addMode = !$scope.addMode;
        $("#txtHotelName").focus();

    };
```

focus() and select() don't work so I took them out. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Added a directive that should work; check the plunk after EDIT in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout was the correct answer. I placed the following code at the end of the 
toggleAdd function:

```
setTimeout(function () {

            $("#txtHotelName").focus();

        }, 1000);
```

I didn't think it would work but it did. Strange that adding text to the text box doesn't need a timeout to work but placing the focus there does.
Thanks to everyone who replied.

Answer (score 0):

There's attribute for autofocus put it on the desired input

```
<input autofocus />
```

Alternative is try to set angular timeout because probably the element isn't renedred yet when you try to focus it

```
$timeout(function(){
  $("#txtHotelName").focus();
});
```

you can give it 100ms for instance `$timeout(function(){}, 100)` if above doesn't help

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion however.

Comment: @leesider Are you sure because I have try it on your example site on `<input name="hotelname">` and it worked

Comment: No it didn't work for me. I changed the line in the cshtml file to this: `code`  <input autofocus type="text" name="hotelname" id="txtHotelName" maxlength="25" size="40" data-ng-model="newhotel.HotelName" required ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\- ]*$/" /> `code`

Comment: I will try the timeout but I have a feeling it is not because the text box hasn't rendered yet because I am able to make text appear in the text box using jQuery "Val()" but I cannot make the cursor appear there. I think some code somewhere else may be interfering with it.

Comment: @leesider I doubt that unless you try to focus something else at the same time. My opiniion is your code focuses not rendered element but try it and give me feedback

Answer (score 0):

I made a directive that should work:

```
angular.module('example', [])
.directive('focusOnShow', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      function focusElem() {
        $timeout(function() { elem[0].focus() }, 0)
      }
      console.log(angular.element(elem))
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngShow, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal) { focusElem() }
      })

      scope.$watch(attrs.ngHide, function(newVal) {
        if (!newVal) { focusElem() }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

and in your html (add the directive to the input you want to focus):

```
<input type="text" focus-on-show>
```

Plunk here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oO117vQhszC6gfFSHV1Y?p=preview

EDIT: Noticed you have the ng-hide on the parent element instead, try this one then:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return elem.parent().hasClass('ng-hide') }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  newVal && focusElem()
})
```

New plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/PVT8jluVn95T6Yq18nRE?p=preview